# Can the results from the Wagtail API be cached or have a `Cache-Control` header set?

Tags: django-rest-framework, wagtail

I'm trying to cache one of the API views from Wagtail. I've searched for ways to cache Django REST and found a way by injecting the `Cache-Control` in the response.
As seen here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#standard-httpresponse-attributes

This method won't work with Wagtail though since the serializer is part of Wagtail. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wagtail API endpoints are defined in [`wagtail.api.v2.endpoints`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/api/v2/endpoints.py) (and other locations such as [`wagtail.images.api.v2.endpoints`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/images/api/v2/endpoints.py) and can be subclassed to provide custom behaviour such as setting additional headers on the response. For example, to add the Cache-Control header to the detail view of `PagesAPIEndpoint`:

```
from wagtail.api.v2.endpoints import PagesAPIEndpoint

class CachedPagesAPIEndpoint(PagesAPIEndpoint):
    def detail_view(self, request, pk):
        response = super().detail_view(request, pk)
        response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
        return response
```

Then, [in your api.py](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/api/v2/configuration.html#configure-endpoints), register your custom `CachedPagesAPIEndpoint` in place of the standard `PagesAPIEndpoint`.

Comment: wouldn't be possible to use the "never_cache" method decorator? 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers